# Show that $\frac{1}{x^4 \sin^2 (x) +1} \in L^1([0, \infty))$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

This is question 10.20c from Apostol's Mathematical Analysis.  Basically, I am trying to show that 
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{x^4 \sin^2(x)+1} \in L^1([0,\infty))
$$

I know that for some value $k$, I can create $A=\{x| \frac{1}{x^4 \sin^2(x)+1}<\frac{1}{x^k}\}$ which is measurable and also
$$
\int_A \frac{1}{x^4 \sin^2(x)+1} dx
$$ 
is finite.

I am stuck trying to show that $\int_{A^c} f(x)$ is finite.  I have been trying to do this by constructing a set $B=\cup_n Bn$ where each $B_n$ is disjoint and is centered around some multiple of $\pi$.  I am stuck, however, in trying to construct these sets such that the boundaries of each $B_n$ are in $A$ and so that $\mu(B) = \sum_n \mu(B_n)$ is finite.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A(\alpha)=\{x\mid x^4\sin^2(x)\geqslant x^\alpha\}$ and $B(\alpha)=\{x\mid x^4\sin^2(x)\leqslant x^\alpha\}$ for some $\alpha\gt0$, then
$$
\int_{A(\alpha)}f\leqslant\int_1^\infty\frac{\mathrm dx}{x^\alpha},
$$
which converges if $\alpha\gt1$.

On the other hand, $B_n(\alpha)=B(\alpha)\cap[n\pi-\frac\pi2,n\pi+\frac\pi2]$ is roughly the set of real numbers $n\pi+z$ with $|z|\leqslant\frac\pi2$ such that $(n\pi)^4\sin^2(z)\leqslant(n\pi)^\alpha$, that is $|\sin z|\leqslant(n\pi)^{\alpha/2-2}$. Thus, if $\alpha\lt4$, 
$$
\int_{B_n(\alpha)}f\leqslant|B_n(\alpha)|\sim2(n\pi)^{\alpha/2-2}.
$$
Note that the series
$$
\sum_nn^{\alpha/2-2},
$$
converges for every $\alpha\lt2$. Finally the decomposition into $A(\alpha)$ and $B(\alpha)=\bigcup\limits_nB_n(\alpha)$ shows that $f$ is integrable for every $\alpha$ in $(1,2)$.

Comment: I really appreciate the help, but I'm a little confused by the step where you defined each $B_n(α)$. I understand that you started with the interval $[nπ−\frac{π}{2},nπ+\frac{π}{2}]$, but I am confused by the step where you say that $(nπ)^4sin^2(z)≤(nπ)^α$.  Do you mean $(nπ+z)^4sin^2(z)≤(nπ)^α$

Comment: never mind, I figured it out.  Thanks!